# Sticky element stops being sticky when certain height is exceeded

Tags: html, css, position, css-grid, sticky

I am experiencing a problem with a sticky header I am trying to implement. I simplified the code for y'all to reproduce:

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    kkk
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav">
    kkk
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
  height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "nav main main";
}

.header {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  grid-area: main;

  
.item {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
 }
```

As you can see I have a simple layout with a header, a navigation menu and a main section. I want the header to remain on screen when scrolling down the results in the main section but when I exceed a certain height (potentially of the navigation menu?) the header disappears anyway.

Does any of you know a simple solution for this problem, that works with my layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min-height instead of height on the page element

```css
.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "nav main main";
}

.header {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  background: red;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  grid-area: main;

  
.item {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    kkk
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav">
    kkk
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
    <div class="item">kkk</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the job perfectly, thank you! :)